# When creating a microsoft forms trigger in a logic app I can only see forms I created

Tags: azure-logic-apps, microsoft-forms

Sorry in advance if this question seems naïve.

I'm currently trying to configure a logic app that triggers based on a form being submitted via Microsoft Forms.

This form is located in one of my organizations groups (which my user has access to). When attempting to create the trigger the only forms I can see in the dropdown are ones that I created myself and are under My Forms in microsoft forms.

I'm unsure of the steps to make the form visible / available so I can create a trigger for it. Any help would be appreciated. FYI the logic app is going to be used to create a work item based on the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer, not sure why I didn't catch this the first time I read this.

[image]